# Why Symfony NotNull contraint throws an error for false?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.4

I'm facing an issue dealing with a [`NotNull`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotNull.html) constraint in a Symfony form validation.

Using the following form :

```
class SchedulableType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($options) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
                $form
                    ->add('dateFrom', DateTimeType::class, array(
                        'constraints' => array(
                            new NotNull()
                        ),
                        'widget' => 'single_text', // In order to manage format
                        'format' => 'y-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
                    ))
                    ->add('dateTo', DateTimeType::class, array(
                        'constraints' => array(
                            new NotNull()
                        ),
                        'widget' => 'single_text', // In order to manage format
                        'format' => 'y-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
                    ))
                    ->add('value', $options['valueType'], $options['valueOptions']);
        });
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'valueType' => null,
            'valueOptions' => array(),
        ));
    }
}
```

The data in my event are the following :

```
array (size=3)
  'dateFrom' => boolean false
  'dateTo' => boolean false
  'value' => string 'value' (length=5)
```

But I'm getting the following error message :

```
{
    "status": "400",
    "title": "This value should not be null.",
    "source": {
        "source": {
            "pointer": "/SCHEDULABLE/dateFrom/0"
        }
    }
},
{
    "status": "400",
    "title": "This value should not be null.",
    "source": {
        "source": {
            "pointer": "/SCHEDULABLE/dateTo/0"
        }
    }
}
```

Why a [`NotNull`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotNull.html) constraint throws an error if my value is `false` ?

You can have a look at the constraint class : [symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/NotNullValidator.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/NotNullValidator.php)

**PS** : The form validation is used in an API, it's why the error is JSON formatted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's basically because those fields are `DateTimeType` so it [tries to cast value to a valid `\DateTime`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6e95c2ad27e759b8ba274cb468af2c0f9160e0b9/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/DateTimeToStringTransformer.php#L109-L113) and since it won't happen anyway, it store a `null` value.
Remember that the cycle is

1. Data handling
2. Object (or form) population via setter/adder/public properties
3. Validation (in fact you're the responsible for this via `isValid()`)

If you would like to accept `false` and implement some kind of logic like "set today date", you need to do yourself (maybe with [FormEvents](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html)?)

Comment: I was searching on the wrong way, thank you for this clear explanation.
I will handle it with a [custom constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html), it looks like suitable.